how to edit the style of the preview image in Laravel Filamentphp FileUpload
I want to edit the style of the preview section the pre-upload from this style screenshot 1 to something like the example I show down.
The only thing that I can control is the height, I searched many places nothing works.
FileUpload::make('img')
    ->multiple()
    ->image()
    ->imagePreviewHeight('100')
    ->label('رفع صورة')

screenshot 1
example
I tried to play a little bit with css by searching some files but it feels not good way to approach what I'm looking for and I believe there are some proper ways to do it.
